# exists method does not work as expected in laravel for checking row existence

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a little rest API,and in my controller a `json` response works only if the `$object->exists()` returns `1` but for any other cases it sends errors
Here is my code :

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $category=Category::find($id);
        return response()->json(
          ($category->exists()?$category:["message"=>"not found"])
        );
    }
```

When the category is found i get row back in a `json format` and it doesn't work for the `false` case.
What i wanted to do first was that in a case of an `error` to return message and code `404 code status` like the following code:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $category=Category::find($id);
        return response()->json(
          ($category->exists()?$category:(["message"=>"not found"],404))
        );
    }
```

But nothing worked either while my code seems well written and i'm getting the exact same problem with the destroy method:

```
 public function destroy($id)
    {
      $category=Category::find($id);
      if($category->exists()){
        $category->delete();
        return response()->json(array("message"="category deleted","success"=>true));
      }
        return response()->json(array("message"=>"Not found"),404);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Category::find($id);` will return a `Category` object when the record actually exists in the database. However, if the record does not exist, it will return `null`. Because of this, you are trying to call the function `exists()` on `null` which is not possible.

It's better to check if the variable has the value `null` or use a [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) if you are on php7.

```
$category = Category::find($id);
return response()->json(
    $category ?? ["message" => "not found"], 
    404
);
```

Comment: Laravel has out of box method `findOrFail` then Why are you trying so hard to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

> What i wanted to do first was that in a case of an error to return
>   message and code 404 code status like the following code

The `findOrFail()` method exists for exactly this case:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
    return $category;
}
```

In the event that no model was found, `findOrFail()` will throw a ModelNotFoundException which causes a 404 to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

`exists()` is a builder method and you are executing it on a model instance.

As you are already fetching the model instance from the database so you can instead check if it is empty or not. You can do something like:

```
empty($category) ? ["message"=>"not found"] : $category
```